# Customize Alternate Control Methods(Face recognition) to control mouseclick in macOS?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, macos-mojave, accessibility, opencv

[image]

In macOS Accessibility , there is a section called Pointer Control, and in 'Alternate Control Methods', I can use Raise Eyebrows to perform a left click, So I wanna ask,  Is there any way to customize this behaviour, e.g Rase Eyebrows to open specific App, or Is there any alternative app can achieve this in macOS?